# twig problem, how to override base templates?

Tags: theming

I have installed Bootstrap and the Radix theme, and created a sub-theme, which is all working OK. But I am unable to get some of my twig files to override the base theme twig files...

The file themes/custom/mytheme/templates/page/page.html.twig contains:
{% embed '@radix/navbar/navbar.twig' with {

I would like to create a navbar.twig in my subtheme and use that instead of the standard radix one. Changes I make to themes/contrib/radix/src/components/navbar/navbar.twig will show up on my site (as this is what the embed refers to), but changes to themes/custom/mytheme/src/components/navbar/navbar.twig do not.

**How can I change that embed line so that it includes the subtheme twig rather than the base?** It's some kind of twig namespace? I have not been able to figure out where it is defined.

Comment: You can't. Create your own `page.html.twig` instead and use `{% embed '@my_subtheme/navbar/... %}` in there.

Comment: And yes, `@radix` is a namespace. Drupal provides a Twig `@namespace` for every theme and every module.

Comment: @Hudri where is the my_subtheme namespace defined? Because when I change it from radix to mytheme I just get "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."  I have used the directory name (which is "mytheme"), and the name in mytheme.info.yml after name: (which is MyTheme) and neither worked

Comment: Use the machine name = directory of your subtheme. If your theme's machine name is `johndoe`, use `@johndoe`. Only lowercase, digits and underlines are allowed for machine names. The Twig file must be placed below the `templates` subdir, but do not include `templates/` in the embed string

Comment: I got it now, thanks!  You should post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Create your own `page.html.twig` instead and use `{% embed '@my_subtheme/navbar/... %}` in there.

Use the machine name == directory of your subtheme for `@my_subtheme`. Only lowercase, digits and underlines are allowed for machine names. The Twig file must be placed below the templates subdir, but do not include `templates/` in the embed string